# How do I Locate and click markers in websites where google maps is embedded using selenium webdriver in Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, maps, marker

I already found something that could help me, but there is information missing so that I can't understand ecactly what to do:
I think I have to do Set "optimized : false", but I don't know where I could change this.

The website I want to extract data from is plugshare.com.
The markers are not actually elements, so I don't have an ID or name to make this task simple.
I found out, that the infowindow that opens when I click manually on a marker have a class and a position.
When I click with selenium at the class="gm-style-iw-a" ,where I think is the marker, there happens something: the right third of the browser window gets white(looks like the page "unloads"?)

I think every marker have the same class. I thougt when I click with selenium at something that exists multiple times it just clicks the first. Why does this not happen?

The code I have so far is

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'PATH')
driver.get('https://www.plugshare.com/xhtml')

close = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[7]/md-dialog/md-toolbar/div/button/md-icon')
close.click() #closes commercial window

search_field = driver.find_element_by_id('input-0')
search_field.send_keys('New York', Keys.ENTER)

mark = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.gm-style-iw-a')
mark.click()
```

Has someone an idea what to do?

Thank you very much!